# jQueryValidate - check if a control is required without triggering validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to show asterisks for controls which are required. The code was working fine with required class but now I have two fields, company and name. Only one of them is required based on other elements value. Is it possible to check if an input is required without validating the control or the form?

Example html structure:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="CompanyName">Company Name</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" class="form-control required">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
validationOptions: {
    ignore: ":disabled,:hidden",

    rules: {
        CompanyName: {
            required: function () {
                return ($("#ContactName").val().length === 0);
            }
        },
        ContactName: {
            required: function () {
                return ($("#CompanyName").val().length === 0);
            }
        }
    },

    onkeyup: function (element) {
        const $parent = $(element).parents(".form-group");

        if ($(element).valid()) {
            $parent.removeClass("invalid");
        } else {
            $parent.addClass("invalid");
        }
    },

    onfocusout: function () {
        if ($("form").valid()) {
            $("form.error").removeClass("error");
            $("form .invalid").removeClass("invalid");
        }
    },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        const $parent = $(element).parents(".form-group");

        if ($(element).hasClass("error")) {
            $parent.addClass("invalid");
        } else {
            $parent.removeClass("invalid");
        }
    },

    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        $.each(validator.successList, function (index, item) {
            $(item).parents(".form-group").removeClass("invalid");
        });
        const errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            $.each(validator.errorList, function (index, item) {
                $(item.element).parents(".form-group").addClass("invalid");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I can have my code inside required callbacks above but that wouldn't be a generic solution.

I want to be able to call following function many times to update (bootstrap) asterisks on the form based on required state of the fields.

```
appendFormControlAsterisk: function ($panel) {
    //removeFormControlAsterisk($panel);

    let $controls = $(".form-control.required");

    $controls.each(function () {
        const $label = $(this).parents(".form-group").find(">.control-label");

        $label.html($label.html() + " <span class='text-danger'>*</span>");
    });
},
```

Trying to accomplish something like:

```
appendFormControlAsterisk: function ($panel) {
    //removeFormControlAsterisk($panel);

    let $controls = $(".form-control");

    $controls.each(function () {
        if ($(this).isRequired()) {
            const $label = $(this).parents(".form-group").find(">.control-label");

            $label.html($label.html() + " <span class='text-danger'>*</span>");
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is it possible to check if an input is required without validating the control or the form?*

There is no method as part of the jQuery Validate plugin that will return a list of declared, defined, or assigned rules. (*you could look at the values inside of the `settings.rules` object, but this is not dynamic or comprehensive*)

However, there is an undocumented method built into the plugin called `.check()` that will check validity without triggering any of the error messages.  It's not confined to the `required` rule, just validity.  It would effectively only be looking for the `required` rule during the time the field is blank.

In other words on a blank form, this method will **always** tell whether the field is `required` without triggering messages.

You must attach it to the validator object, and the argument must be a DOM element.

```
$('#myform').validate().check($('[name="test3"]')[0]) // <-- returns a boolean if defined
```

OR

```
var validator = $('#myform').validate({...}); // initialize plugin with options

validator.check($('[name="test3"]')[0]) // <-- returns a boolean if defined
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/we2johru/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/we2johru/2/)**

Note that this method only returns a boolean when rules are defined.  Without defined rules, this method will return `undefined`.

Comment: As I see this does the trick. It returns `undefined` when the field is not required anymore and true/false when required.

Answer (score 3):

Below code sample should do the trick for you.

```
appendFormControlAsterisk: function ($panel) {
    //removeFormControlAsterisk($panel);

    let $controls = $(".form-control");

    $controls.each(function () {
        // if ($(this).isRequired()) {
        if ($(this).rules().required) {
            const $label = $(this).parents(".form-group").find(">.control-label");

            $label.html($label.html() + " <span class='text-danger'>*</span>");
        }
    });
},
```

If you don't have .form-control class on each element, then you can get the elements array from plugin's .elements() method and loop them with checking their .rules() method.

```
const elements = $("#signupform").validate().elements();
for (let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    const $el = $(elements[i]);
    if ($el.rules().required) {
        $el.parents(".form-group").find(">.control-label").append(" <span class='text-danger'>*</span>");
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

[JSBin Demo](https://jsbin.com/lakecab/edit?js,output) added.

Comment: Sadly $(this).rules().required doesn't return true for conditionally required fields. This worked like my previous code.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy please check the demo at updated answer and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Based on examples of [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) your rules could be modified like in the below example to solve your problem.

```
 rules: {
    CompanyName: {
      required: {
        depends: function(element) {
          return $("#ContactName").val().length === 0;
        }
      }
    },
    ContactName: {
      required: {
        depends: function(element) {
          return $("#CompanyName").val().length === 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**OR**

```
 rules: {
    CompanyName: {
      required: {
        depends: function(element) {
          if($("#ContactName").val().length === 0) {
              $("#ContactName").removeClass("required");
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }             
        }
      }
    },
    ContactName: {
      required: {
        depends: function(element) {
          if($("#CompanyName").val().length === 0) {
              $("#CompanyName").removeClass("required");
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Finally**

> An alternative method would be to use grouping.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="CompanyName">Company Name</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" class="form-control required">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="ContactName">Contact Name</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="ContactName" name="ContactName" class="form-control required">
    </div>
</div>
  // Use require_from_group to ensure at least one of the fields is complete
  rules: {
    ContactName: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".required"]
    },
    CompanyName: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".required"]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @HasanGürsoy i know i did not explain my answer well, but it does solve your problem. go to https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ check for the ***example*** that `Specifies a contact element as required and as email address, the latter depending on a checkbox being checked for contact via email.`. That example shows how to nest elements together and create the logic you want. For you what is "Required" is for at least one field to have value.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy Please check the edit this is exactly what you want.

Comment: Nice to know but I don't have problem requiring only one of the controls. I need to update visible asterisk signs for all required controls. Meaning when field A is filled B is no more **required** and doesn't need to show asterisk anymore.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy your `.required` class applies an asterisk beside your input elements? You could use the first example using `depends` i will make a small edit.

Comment: Yes, to the labels before the element.

Answer (score 2):

So as I understand, each of your input element will have `form-control` class, and `required` class would be only for selected elements. Based on this, below is a snippet that will assign asterisk only to those, that have `required` as class.

**Logic:**
Looping through elements that have `form-control` class, and check using `hasClass()`, if they have `required` class too. If yes, append the danger asterisk to it.

```js
$(".form-control").each(function() {
  var requiredHtml = "<span class='text-danger'>*</span>";
  if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('label').append(requiredHtml);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="CompanyName">Company Name</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" class="form-control required">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="designation">Designation</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="designation" name="designation" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My code already does that. The problem is I need to append asterisk to those which don't have .required but at the time of checking are required.

Comment: That should be easy with above code. Instead of `if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {` change it to `if (!$(this).hasClass('required')) {`

Comment: "I need to append asterisk to those which don't have .required **but at the time of checking are required**."